# Which event should I use to load a store which will populate a form in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

When a view is brought into the viewport, I'd like to be able to load a store and set the model retrieved onto the form within the view.  However, I'm not quite sure which event I should be using for this purpose.

Should this be done within the 'Painted' event of the view, should the view fire back to the controller which then populates the view or is there some other recommended way of doing this?

Currently have this in my view:

```
  listeners: {
        painted: function () {
            var contactStore = Ext.getStore("theContactDetailsStore");

             contactStore.load({
                    scope: this,
                    callback: function (record, operation, success) {
                        if (success && record[0]) {                            
                            this.setRecord(record[0]);                                     
                        }
                    }
                });
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to handle this:

1. Create view first and in its initialize function create & load store. The code for creating an loading could easily be part of controller by firing corresponding event from initialize. This might look ugly because your view might not look good without data , but still this would be faster so please take care of masking & unmasking(in load callback of store) the view.
2. Create your store first and in its load callback fire the event with data(store records etc) which will create the view using that data. This would look slow initially because you won't see any part of view until store is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The painted event should be used to perform some low level DOM operations like fix elements size, position, etc.
This is what I suggest you:

- Load first the store eventually masking the viewport with a "Loading..." message before, so that if the operation takes time the user has not the impression that the app crashed.
- On the store "load" callback show your form view passing the wanted data model as a "record" configuration param.

In this way your form will be immediately shown filled with your record data.

PS: If you mask the viewport before to load the store, remember to unmask it inside the "load" callback before to show your form.

Comment: Ok great, but I'm still not clear where the load on the store should occur.  What event should I be listening for? Where, in the controller or view?

Comment: Just call the store "load" method setting the callback function where you will show your form. Do that from a controller. Take a look at the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load

Comment: Ok I understand the load method callback. I've added a code sample to my question. Currently another controller shows the view and I use the painted event in the view to load. I don't like code inside the view listener, and I don't want to load the store in the controller either because the controller is used for a different view. Hope you understand my dilemma...